# Anagram char arrays

Tags: c++, string, pointers, recursion, char

So i have this algorithm in my c++ book

```
int anagrams(char *x, char *y) {
  char *p;
  if (!*x && !*y) return 1;
  p = strchr(y, *x);
  if (!p) return 0;
  *p = NULL;
  strcat(y, p + 1);
  return anagrams(x + 1, y)
}
```

It takes x first element, verifies if y has it, and if y has it, it is deleted. I don't really understand.
So, strchr returns a pointer to where x appears in y. And after that, i don't really understand.By the way

```
char a[] = "children" ;
char *p = strchr(a, 'i') ;
*p = NULL";
```

Why here everything after 'h' dissapears? P points to 'i', so shouldn t just 'i' dissapear?
Thanks! (i m still a beginner)

Comment: Are you sure that this a C++ book? The code rather looks like pure C. (It doesn't mean that it cannot be compiled in C++ as well but idiomatic C++ code should be taught in a different way.) FYI: [Kate Gregory "Stop teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) ;-)

Comment: Sure, my bad, my book is c/c++

Comment: For your first exposed snippet, please, provide an example how it is called. Even better would be to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Concerning *Why here everything after 'h' dissapears?*:

```
char a[] = "children" ;
char *p = strchr(a, 'i') ;
*p = NULL";
```

1. There is a typo: It should probably be `*p = NULL;` (The double quote `"` is wrong.)
2. `p` is of type `char*`. Applying the de-reference operator `*` results in the pointee type. Hence, the *expression* `*p` is of type `char`. (Please, don't confuse this with the *declaration* `char *p` which declares a variable `p` of type `char*`.) `NULL` is intended to denote a null pointer. (In C, it might be defined as `#define NULL (void*)0`. In C++, `nullptr` should be favored over `NULL`.) Assigning a null pointer to a `char` is … confusing but the C compiler (as well as the C++ compiler) probably implicitly converts it back to a plain `0`.

   I compiled this with `gcc -std=c11` as well as with `g++ -std=c++17`. In both cases, the compiler makes a warning but provides an executable binary:

   - [**C: Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d8de45f65060f4a)
     Output:

     ```
     warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       *p = NULL;
     ```
   - [**C++: Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905e73db0066237b)
     Output:

     ```
     warning: converting to non-pointer type 'char' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
       *p = NULL;
     ```

   So, it should be `*p = 0;` or even more clearly `*p = '\0';` which is semantically identical but exposes the intention more clearly.

Considering this, a fixed version would be:

```
char a[] = "children" ;
char *p = strchr(a, 'i') ;
*p = '\0';
```

It overrides the element with `i` with a `\0` which is the string terminator in C strings.

`char a[]` was before:

```
{ 'c', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'n', '\0' }
```

and becomes after this assignment

```
{ 'c', 'h', '\0', 'l', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'n', '\0' }
```

So, it still has the same length but using it with a C string function (like e.g. `printf("%s", a);`) will consider the first found string terminator.
Hence, it will print `ch` only.

Demo for illustration:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char a[] = "children" ;
  char *p = strchr(a, 'i') ;
  *p = '\0';
  // printing a c string
  printf("a[]: '%s'\n", a);
  // print a[] element wise
  std::cout << "a[]: {";
  const char *sep = " ";
  for (char c : a) {
    std::cout << sep << '\'';
    if (c >= ' ' && c < '\x7f') std::cout << c;
    else std::cout << '\\' << std::oct << (unsigned)(unsigned char)c << std::dec;
    std::cout << '\'';
    sep = ", ";
  }
  std::cout << " }\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a[]: 'ch'
a[]: { 'c', 'h', '\0', 'l', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'n', '\0' }
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a501deca4591ce8)

---

A note about OPs C/C++ book:

It is a fact that the language C++ evolved out of the already existing language C. C and C++ are still related to each other. E.g. parts of the C standard library are adopted in the C++ standard library.

Nevertheless, these are two independent languages with their respective own standards.

- There are C statements which work in C++ as well.
- There are things in C which work in C++ a bit different.
- There are things in C which doesn't work in C++ and vice versa.

Examples for the last:

- [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/auto) is a valid storage class in C. In C++, this meaning has been invalidated since C++11, and the keyword got a new semantic: [placeholder type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)
- [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are an optional feature of the C99 standard (and newer) but not of any C++ standard. Some compilers (e.g. `g++`) support it as proprietary extension in C++.
- [Type Punning with `union`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) is legalized (to some degree) by the C standard but prohibited by the C++ standard.
- Of course, C++ introduced a variety of new keywords (with new semantics) like e.g. `class` and `template` which are not available in C and would be interpreted as plain identifiers.

---

An (admittedly a bit contrived) example to show that the same source code may result in different semantics in C vs. C++:

```
  auto a = 'a';
  printf("sizeof a: %d\n", (int)sizeof a);
```

In C11:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  auto a = 'a';
  printf("sizeof a: %d\n", (int)sizeof a);
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof a: 4
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51c9af0a2348ab7a)

`auto` is storage class. A type is missing in `auto a`. The C compiler defaults it to `int`.

In C++11:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using std::printf; // pull printf() into global scope

int main()
{
  auto a = 'a';
  printf("sizeof a: %d\n", (int)sizeof a);
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof a: 1
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbb607383c0ec14f)

`auto` determines the type of `a` from its initialization. In C++, character constants are of type `char` (in opposition to C, where they have type `int`).